# column row class in Foundation 6 practical uses

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

```
<div class="column row">
  Row column
</div>
```

Foundation documentation did not give any practical example on using this feature. Does anybody know how to use this properly? Is not it the same as .container in Bootstrap?

Comment: You probably have read this, http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html. I found a fiddle using column as interface, http://jsfiddle.net/joanllenas/6zojkm48/.

Comment: <div class="column row"> is the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases you would create column divs inside row divs like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        Foo
    </div>
</div>
```

If the column div is 12 wide you can replace that structure with:

```
<div class="column row">
    Foo
</div>
```

Is it practical? If you have the first scenario littered throughout your html then maybe yes.

And, as for readability maybe not so much.

Answer (score -1):

You have to place the column inside of a row. Its very similar to bootstrap. Here's a link to help.

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
  <div class="large-6 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="column row"> is the question